# Find a Mobius transformation that maps $i,-i,1$ to $0,2,\infty$ respectively.

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

Find a Mobius transformation that maps $i,-i,1$ to $0,2,\infty$ respectively.

$$w(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$

I think I don't have enough clear elements here, and I don't know which numbers to plugin and why for $a,b,c$ and $d$. This one that maps to $\infty$ I have no idea, how to work with. Can someone help with this. I feel like I have no clear direction, and that too much is unclear and unknown.

Comment: You don't actually need four unknowns, only three

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first condition is
$$
f(i)=\frac{ai+b}{ci+d}=0.
$$
This implies $ai+b$ equals what?
Next, 
$$
f(-i)=\frac{b-ai}{d-ci}=2,
$$
so $b-ai=2d-2ci$.
Finally, 
$$
f(1)=\frac{a+b}{c+d}=\infty,
$$
so $c+d=0$. We can now conclude $c=-d$. As noted in the comments, we have freedom in the variables since we have less restrictions than free variables, so lets say $c=1$, $d=-1$. Can you finish from here?

Comment: Thanks, this condition with $\infty$ completely flew over my head. :)